# bat para cambiar las extensiones

Tags: windows, cmd, .bat

tratando de usar [loombok](/questions/tagged/loombok) para agregarle mejoras me halle que algunos de los archivos que contiene el jar vienen con la extension .SCL.lombok al extraer el archivo comprimido.

deseo renombrar todos los archivos .SCL.lombok a .class de la carpeta actual y las subcarpetas.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%f in (*.SCL.lombok) do (
  set "file=%%f"
  set "newname=!file:.SCL.lombok=.class!"
  echo Renombrando "!file!" a "!newname!"
  ren "!file!" "!newname!"
)

echo Extensiones de archivos cambiadas con éxito

endlocal
```

El problema es que no esta entrando al `for`

[image: codigo en ejecucion]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si pruebas con esto?

```
 @echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s /a-d "*.SCL.lombok"') do (
  set "file=%%f"
  set "newname=!file:.SCL.lombok=.class!"
  echo Copiando "!file!" a "!newname!"
  copy "!file!" "!newname!"
  echo Eliminando "!file!"
  del "!file!"
)

echo on

echo Extensiones de archivos cambiadas con éxito

endlocal
```

esta es una prueba echa en mi PC

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me dice File Not Found

Comment: Para verificar que el patrón de búsqueda de archivos está correcto, puedes intentar ejecutar el comando dir de forma independiente y asegurarte de que encuentra los archivos que buscas. Por ejemplo `dir /b /s /a-d "*.SCL.lombook"`

Comment: lombok lleva solo una o.... probando de nuevo

Comment: ahora dice The syntax of the command is incorrect

Comment: parece que la sintaxis del ren es incorrecta

Comment: probe con `ren "%%f" *.class` pero ahora se llaman `.SCL.class` fuuuuuuuu

Comment: jajajaja, mira cambie para no usar ren que me estaba dando problemas asi que use el siguiente paso logioco

Comment: asi funciono a la primera genial gracias :D