# como usar el AST de lombok para compilar

Tags: java, maven, lombok

Estoy tratando de compilar un proyecto en el que trabaje hace tiempo llamado lombok-jedi que extiende lombok agregando mas patrones de diseño de manera similar a la implementación de builder que tiene lombok (@Builder).

La limitación es que algunas clases que necesito para compilarlo no me las reconoce ya que dentro del jar en vez de venir como `.class` vienen como `.SCL.lombok` ( ya se es de lo mas extraño ).

Antes recuerdo que tras mucho batallar seguía este procedimiento:

1. descargar el jar
2. cambiar la extension a .zip
3. descomprimir
4. modificar una a una las extensiones conforme las fuera usando
5. comprimir la carpeta
6. cambiar la extensión de .zip a .jar

Luego migre el proyecto de [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) a maven y agregue el paso

7. correr un install de maven en modo offline (si hasta desconectaba el cable de red para estar seguro)

Y este procedimiento me funcionaba hace unos años, pero el día de hoy que intento compilar no me funciona.
He intentado compilar tanto con con las ultimas versiones de NetBeans como de IntelliJ IDEA con exactamente el mismo problema

> C:\Users\usuario\IdeaProjects\lombok-jedi\pt.iscte.lombok.jedi\src\lombok\javac\handlers\HandleVisitableChildren.java:[35,22] error: package lombok.core.AST does not exist

> [ERROR] C:\Users\usuario\IdeaProjects\lombok-jedi\pt.iscte.lombok.jedi\src\lombok\javac\handlers\HandleVisitableChildren.java:[36,18] error: cannot find symbol

> [ERROR]   symbol:   class AnnotationValues
> location: package lombok.core

> C:\Users\usuario\IdeaProjects\lombok-jedi\pt.iscte.lombok.jedi\src\lombok\javac\handlers\HandleVisitableChildren.java:[37,18] error: cannot find symbol

esto a pesar de que en ambos IDEs si abro las dependencias en la pestaña de proyecto me salen ya listadas las clases que se les modifico la extension (actualmente se cambian todas gracias al script que me ayudaron a corregir en este sitio: [bat para cambiar las extensiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/575962/bat-para-cambiar-las-extensiones)) .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Considero importante dejar esta pregunta a la posteridad en caso de que alguien desee trabajar con estas clases de lombok.

Hay alguna manera de que maven reconozca estas clases para compilar con ellas?

Comment: podrias precompliar las clases por separado usando el jar -cvf en lugar del zip, pues no son lo mismo

Comment: @John tienes razon con eso y otros truquitos ya compila, gustas poner la respuesta para llevarte el credito?

Comment: quisa no el credito pero cuando alguien mas busque en google el problema podra ver que ya esta resuelto, eso ayuda mas a los demas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrias precompliar las clases por separado usando el
`jar -cvf` en lugar del zip, pues no son lo mismo

los algoridmos de zip cambian en el tiempo, tendrias que comprimir con un zip en una maquina con windows xp para que funcione.
para eso esta el "compilador" de java

Comment: exacto normalmente usaba windows xp y funcionaba. Excelente explicacion